# Print file names and folders and sub folders in a specific order

Tags: java, file, printing, console, directory

I want to run a program which will print that print to console all the files (names) for a given directory. Note that any sub-directory should also be printed and the structure should be indent (\t) with any level of the tree.

See attached image with the way it should be printed.

[image: attachment]

What I wrote makes almost the output I need but not exactly, could some one of you help?

This is what I did:

```
import java.io.File;

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String root = "C:\\CE";//root directory , change directory name to which one you like
    String tab="\t";
    String n="";
    int d=0;
    printFilesAndDirectoriesNames(root,tab,n,d);
}

public static void printFilesAndDirectoriesNames(String root,String t,String n,int d) {
    int directoryAgain=0;
    int temp=0;
    String tab=t;
    String name=n;  
    File folder = new File(root);
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
//run over all folder+ subfolders by calling this function over and over again
        for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) 
        {
            //is file
          if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) 
          {
              //if temp == 0 folder nameis being printed
              if(temp==0)
                {
                 if(name==""){
                 System.out.println(folder.getName()+ " [Directory]");
                 temp++;
                 name=folder.getName();

                 }
                 else if(name!=folder.getName()&&name!="") {

                     System.out.println(tab+folder.getName()+ " [Directory]");
                     tab=tab+"\t";
                     temp++;
                     name=folder.getName();
                }
                 }
            System.out.println(tab + listOfFiles[i].getName());
          }
          //is directory
          else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
              directoryAgain++;
              printFilesAndDirectoriesNames(root+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName(),tab,name,directoryAgain);

          }}

    }
}
```

Comment: this is what i want to see
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rlgdddv7uy45omv/1.png

Answer (score 0):

See [Walking the File Tree](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html) tutorial.

It includes the following examples to demonstrate the file walking mechanism:

- Find – Recurses a file tree looking for files and directories that match a particular glob pattern. This example is discussed in Finding Files.
- Chmod – Recursively changes permissions on a file tree (for POSIX systems only).
- Copy – Recursively copies a file tree.
- WatchDir – Demonstrates the mechanism that watches a directory for files that have been created, deleted or modified. Calling this program with the -r option watches an entire tree for changes. For more information about the file notification service, see Watching a Directory for Changes.

Wlaking the file tree is a much easier method to do what you want.